# MySQL Sync Tables between two database on different computer

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, database

I have two databases hosted on different computers. One client one server. On the client side, data will be captured constantly (min 10 entries per minute) and data will be uploaded to server for further processing. Client will also occasionally sync some information (such as product info) that can only be updated on the server side. For example:

```
CLIENT TABLE
product
product_ID| product_Name
1         | Tomato
2         | Potato
3         | Buritto


SERVER TABLE
product
product_ID | product_Name
1          | Tomato
3          | Zucchini
4          | Peas
```

Ok, Client will read product table from server in one way direction (whatever gets changed on server, client will follow). I am thinking to do it this way:

1. Read everything on Server table and update the client table using INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement. For example:

   INSERT INTO product SET product_ID=(from server), product_Name=(from server) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_Name=(from server)
2. Delete everything that is not on the Server table anymore. In this example it is product id 2 (Potato) that needs to be deleted on Client table.

How can I achieve second point? Truncating the client table prior to new insert is not an option. Another option that crossed my mind is to scan every row on client table and check if it exist on server table. However, this method is quite slow and undesirable.. Anybody can shed any light?

Comment: How does your problem depart from conventional replication?

Comment: Client table only sync certain columns out of Server table